# Croogo - allows users to add a pictures on a blog site

Tags: image, croogo

I am a new user of Croogo. I need to create a website, like a blog, where users can post and add pictures.

But I don't know how can I proceed, the admin can post trough the admin panel but what about users ? Which function should I use ?

I didn't found any tutorial on the web and I don't know how it works.

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: No offence here, but what kond of answer do you expect to get from such a question? It seems to broad for me. Stack Overflow is better suited for more specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better try to create it in the Vendor/croogo/croogo/Nodes path in the respective controller and view folder. You can start from here. Hope this will help you.